# How to create valid war file from /src & /WebContent folder in CLI?

Tags: java, deployment, build, wildfly, war

I have a project with 2 folders:

- 1) src - contains the Java code files & folders (entity, code, rest,
  timer)
- 2) WebContent - contains folders (META-INF, WEB-INF)

I have not experienced with server-side Java and I would like to ask how I can create **a valid .war** file **using CLI** that can be deployed using the **Wildfly** web admin interface and achieve that project is available and running on URL defined in web.xml file (located in WEB-INF folder).

I tried to deploy war which been created using the following command in root folder (i tried WebContent folder too) but after uploading the .war file the application is not reachable on the given URL (404).

Thanks for any advice.

Edit:

Added actual project structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to move to a build tool of some sort.  There are various options - I'll go over [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) as it is the one I'm most familiar with.

First thing is code organization.  You'll need to organize your code like:

```
src/
    main/
        java/
           com/
               packagename/
                   SomeJavaCode.java
        webapp/
            WEB-INF/
                web.xml
```

So all of your Java code will be somewhere under `src/main/java` in whatever packages you want.  In `src/main/webapp` are files related to your web application.  You should have a minimum of `WEB-INF/web.xml` for a .war file but if you have a .jsp or .html it would go in the webapp directory too.

At the root of the directory you will need a `pom.xml` file.  This is your build file that tells Maven what to do.  A super basic one for a .war file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tld.companyname</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This file only has dependencies on the JEE stack with the Servlet libraries.  These are both marked as "provided" as you don't need to include these in your .war file as Wildfly already provides them.

Note that you are very likely to have additional dependencies for your code.  They need to be added as a `dependency` stanza in the `pom.xml` like the other ones.  If you're not sure what this value should be go to [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/) to search for the correct code to insert.

The output of this will be a .war file in the `target` directory.  This .war file can be deployed to Wildfly.

An extra piece - to help Wildfly determine the root URL path of your .war file, include the file `jboss-web.xml` in your `WEB-INF` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

When you deploy this .war the `jboss-web.xml` file will tell Wildfly to put it under the path `/myapp` in this example.  To me this removes some of the confusion around automatic web app names that can occur.  Note that it is perfectly legitimate to have the `context-root` be `/` so that your .war is at the root of the URL hierarchy.

Once you have all that, you'll need to install Maven and have it on your PATH.  Take a look at the [Maven Install page](http://maven.apache.org/install.html) for details for your O/S.  After this is installed just run:

```
mvn clean package
```

on the command line to generate the .war in your target directory.

**EDIT**

One thing that is different is that you do not need to add the dependencies inside of your code - Maven takes care of that.  So, for example, in your image for the AWS libraries I would just add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.119</version>
</dependency>
```

inside of the `dependencies` block.  Maven will automatically pull this library from the Maven central repository and use it.  You don't need to have it in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory as, when Maven builds, it will automatically include the libries you have in your dependencies (and anything *they* depend on).  Again, just search in https://mvnrepository.com/ for the library you need.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the folder structure and executed the mvn clean package command from root folder and i got a lot of error regarding the dependecies, for example
/help/ContribCacheRefreshTask.java:[11,21] package com.amazonaws does not exist

How I should upgrade the structure or pom.xml file please?

Comment: I think that I will need link local jar libraries in pom.xml?

Comment: I updated the answer @redrom - you just need to add the dependencies and Maven will take care of it.